# Is C++ a recursively enumerable language?

Tags: c++, computation-theory, turing-complete, decidable

I know that C++ is not decidable. But is it recursively enumerable?

Let's define the set of valid C++ programs to be any well defined program under the current C++ standards.

Is it possible to construct a compiler that can always identify valid C++ programs in finite time?

Or is it co-recursively enumerable?

Is it possible to construct a compiler that can always identify *invalid* C++ programs in finite time?

Or neither?

Comment: You might be looking for the [Theoretical Computer Science stackexchange site](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).  This question is not in the least related to actual coding problems.

Comment: "C++ Templates are Turing Complete (2003)", by Todd L. Veldhuizen: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.14.3670

Comment: This question is not a practical programming question. It appears to be a theoretical one. But anyway, consider: `while (Riemann_hypothesis_is_true()) { }`. 1.10.24 says that a program must eventually terminate, call an I/O function, access a volatile object, perform a synchronization operation, or perform an atomic operation. If the Riemann hypothesis is true, then this program is invalid.

Comment: "The implementation may assume that" and "A valid program must" are different things. An implementation may assume that something is true, but just because it isn't doesn't mean the program is invalid.

Comment: BTW, if you have an implementation of Riemann_hypothesis_is_true I'd love to see it :P.

Answer (score 2):

*Is it possible to construct a compiler that can always identify valid C++ programs in finite time?*

Yes. Given enough time and resources a C++ compiler should be able to finish compiling any valid C++ program. A recursively enumerable language requires a turing machine that always terminates and provides a positive answer when the string is in the language, and the compiler does essentially that.

*Is it possible to construct a compiler that can always identify invalid C++ programs in finite time?*

No. The C++ template language is Turing complete, so you can write an infinite recursion in it. Due to the halting problem, it's impossible to determine whether or not a program will ever finish compiling, thus it's impossible to determine whether the C++ program would ever successfully compile.

I once wrote an infinite recursion in C++ templates and tried to compile with gcc. It turns out that gcc has a configurable recursion depth limit.

Comment: Is an infinitely recursive template program invalid by my definition though?

Comment: Do the standards forbid infinite template metaprogramming?

Comment: Good question. Being a practical sort of spec (no formal semantics), I would imagine that the question isn't really addressed.

Comment: In the current draft I found this: 
"The result of an infinite recursion in instantiation is undefined."

Comment: So actually, neither question has a real answer.

Comment: That word "undefined" is used in the Standard to indicate invalid programs.

Comment: Hmm... but we're only looking at template recursion here. If we have two pointers p1 and p2. *p1 = (*p2)++; should be undefined if p1 == p2, but well-defined if p1 != p2. Could there be a compiler that can always prove p1 != p2, and accept the program?

Comment: We're getting into redefining the question again. When talking about strings in the C++ language if we try to consider whether or not the programs make sense or work properly then we're back to the halting problem. Template recursion is important because it's compile time processing. Since the compile time processing has to succeed in order for the program to compile, we need to consider it. Run time processing isn't an issue because we've already created the program by that point, and have the answer. The C++ standard defines which programs can compile, not which ones make sense.

Comment: If we define C++ based on practical compiler implementations, and every compiler has a template recursion depth limit, you could say that no program with infinite template recursion is valid. Since the C++ standard doesn't consider every edge case and leaves some constructs undefined, I think it makes sense to consider a specific implementation if we want to formally define the language.